# Modeling Multiple Depot Vehicle Scheduling Problem in OR-Tools

Tags: or-tools

Is it possible to solve the Multiple Depot Vehicle Scheduling Problem (MDVSP) in OR-tools?

The problem is detailed in [this paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.44.12.1637), but here is a brief summary.

We are given a set of depots and the number of available vehicles at each. We are given a set of timetabled trips, and we know the origin, destination, start time, end time, and a set of depots that can serve a given trip. While connecting two trips, that is assigning a vehicle to serve for two trips sequentially, there may be an unoccupied travel, so called a dead-head trip. There are also dead-heads while going from a depot to the first trip and returning from the last trip to a depot. The objective is to minimize the sum of all dead-head trip costs while ensuring each trip is served by exactly one vehicle and the number of vehicles used does not exceed the availability. (Other trips/links, i.e., occupied trips, must in any case need to be served/traversed; so, there is no need to include them in the objective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to take into account the arc cost only if vehicle is empty. (note: fixed typo)

AFAIK, there is no easy way to do it using OR-Tools. In C++ you may use the DimensionDependentDimension and returning the arc cost if a capacity dimension is zero, and zero otherwise...

0. Also I'm curious why you would like to only count dead-trip e.g. if the overall vehicle route is several time longer with very few dead-trip instead of a shorter route with few dead-trip why would you want to incentive the first one ?
   e.g. a route of 100km with 1km dead-trip is two time better than a 50km route with 2km dead-trip...
1. For multiple depots please take a look at
   [vrp_starts_ends.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_starts_ends.py)
2. For TimeWindows: [vrp_time_windows.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/vrp_time_windows.py)
3. Did you take a look at the documentation ?
   e.g. https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp
4. using `routing.NextVar(A).SetValues([A, B])` you can force the chain `A->B`
   ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L1364-L1366
   note: Solver won't have the possibility to use `A->C->B` even if is shorter than `A->B->C` or `C->A->B` (supposing TW allow both of them...)

Comment: I want to take into account the arc cost only if vehicle **is** empty. The occupied trips have to be made by some vehicle no matter what, and their total cost/distance/time is known priori. So, from a VRP point of view, we can think like, some arcs have to be selected in the solution no matter what. These arcs are scheduled trips. All we need to do in the solution is to find out other arcs that can feasibly connect with these arcs obeying strict arrival and departure times, and of course start from depot and come back to depot constraints.

Comment: Based on your example, there is not 100 or 50 km routes. You may assume the non-dead-trips are always 50 km. So, considering them is just adding a constant to the objective.

Comment: Let me sort of rephrase the question, so it becomes more relevant to OR-tools VRP solver. First, I would like to see a (Python) implementation example of Multi Depot VRP if exists. Then, I would be curious if there is a way to say to the solver: "You have to traverse these edges" (which corresponds to the scheduled trips). Another question is whether time windows can include a harsh window like be at this node exactly at 10 AM, e.g., time window = [10 AM, 10 AM]. If all these have positive answers, I should be able to implement it, I guess.

Comment: In the multi depot example, I tried "routing.NextVar(7).SetValues([7,3])" right after "routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)" It gets into an infinite loop (I assume) and does not provide an output although there is a time limit. Isn't this the right place to add this or is there more to add other than this single line to make it work?

Comment: should work but you need to use `manager.NodeToIndex()` to convert your indices as solver node index "coordinate".
Also for debugging please provide a gist so we can reproduce it otherwise it's just a guesswork game.